# Saw an expression. Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

So, I have a typical problem `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` I know that there is a lot of such problems and answers here, but no one did not help me.

Please, give a real help, insted of blocking my question.

Thanks!

```
Object.keys(CDs).map(key => {
  parseInt(key) === additionalInfo.currentQueue[0] // Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression
    ? CDs[key] += 1
    : CDs[key]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is telling you that you have an orphaned expression there, one that isn't connected to anything. The ternary there will resolve to the value of `CDs[key]` or `CDs[key] + 1`, but the value will be ignored - it's like the `5` in

```
function x() {
  5;
}
```

If you were intending to `map` the keys of `CDs` to a new array, use an arrow function's implicit return instead, by surrounding the expression in parentheses rather than brackets:

```
const result = Object.keys(CDs).map(key => (
  parseInt(key) === additionalInfo.currentQueue[0]
    ? CDs[key] + 1 // were you intending to mutate the original object as well here?
    : CDs[key]
));
```

If you weren't intending to mutate `CDs` during this `map`, you might consider `Object.entries` instead, to give you the key and the value at once:

```
const result = Object.entries(CDs).map(([key, value]) => (
  parseInt(key) === additionalInfo.currentQueue[0]
    ? value + 1
    : value
));
```

Comment: Or just use `{ return ... }`

Comment: Sure, but using an arrow function's implicit return when possible is more terse and (arguably) better due to less syntax noise, as many linters recommend.